# Whole number search in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table which has a column that contains numbers like bellow.

```
287:406:852,248:963:147
```

I'd like to search records which have `287` but not `2870` by using find method in cakephp.

How can I do this?

Comment: Save your data correctly, the way you are doing right now is not good

Comment: Are the numbers delimited by colons only? (I.e. is that comma a delimeter or a thousands separator)?

Comment: @michael Thank you for your suggestion. However, now I have no choice, because tons of records are saved in this way, and I don't have enough authority to change it.

Comment: @AgRizzo The strings may continue like 287:406:852,248:963:147,215:548,576:231,325,698.  The separators are only colons and commas.

Comment: What is the column field type?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which returns the location in a set of comma delimited strings of a search string.

Adjust your search column. *(Assume your column is named **foo**)*

1. Replace any colons with commas using the [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) command

   `REPLACE(foo,':',',')`
2. The SQL `WHERE` code would look like *(assuming $bar is the whole number you are looking for)*:

   `WHERE 0 < FIND_IN_SET($bar, REPLACE(foo,':',','))`

Putting together for Cakephp *(I believe this code will sanitize your $bar variable)*:

`$conditions = array('0 < FIND_IN_SET(?, REPLACE(foo,':',',')' => array($bar));`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, the problem may be solved by another method, but still you answer is so helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sho - If you have another answer, you should post it.

Comment: It's not really the answer for this question but I will share it. We managed to change the way to save the numbers like bellow

0287:0406:0852,0248:0963:0147

Therefore, when I search 0287 by like %%, I don't get 2870. 
However, it's not a perfect solution, because when the saved nums' number of digit increase, we have to do same kind of thing.